# Text width inside algorithm2e environment

Tags: margins, algorithm2e, textwidth

I have included the contents of a simple .tex file using the `algorithm2e` feature. When compiled using an old (2015) version of LaTeX, I get the output as desired. But when compiled with the latest version of LaTeX (either on my own laptop or on Overleaf.com), the textwidth within the `algorithm2e` environment is reduced (as indicated by the right extent of the `snugshade*` environment).

For your reference, I have shared the link to my Dropbox folder containing the LaTeX file with both the outputs (converted to .png from .pdf formats). I cannot seem to find a way to get around this issue. I will appreciate any help on this matter.

Here is the contents of my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\parindent0pt 
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11.0in, left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1.25in,bottom=1.25in, includefoot]{geometry}               
\usepackage[ruled,noend,noline,slide]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{230,230,230}

\title{Textwidth Inside Algorithm2e Environment}
\author{\large\textsc{Sid}\\[2mm] 
\normalsize\textit{Some Institute} \\
\vspace{-5mm}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\caption{\emph{MatVecMult}: A Matrix-Vector Multiplication Procedure }
\begin{snugshade*}
\textbf{Procedure} MatVecMult \\
\textbf{Input}:  $\left\{A_{i,j}\right\}_{i,j=0}^{M,N}$, $\left\{B_j\right\}_{j=0}^N$ \\
\For{$i = 0$ \upshape \textbf{to} $M$}{
$t \gets 0$ \\
\For{$j = 0$ \upshape \textbf{to} $N$}{
$t \gets t + A_{i,j}*B_j$
}
\textbf{end} \\
$C_i \gets t$
}
\textbf{end} \\
\Return $\left\{C_j\right\}_{j=0}^M$ \\
\textbf{End Procedure} MatVecMult
\end{snugshade*}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[Link to my Dropbox Folder Containing the Latex File With Both Outputs](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a2inp5e6v6e275w/AACTE01s8SjfoEG-uQ_OAItZa?dl=0)

Comment: I can confirm the width of the grey box changes between texlive 2016 and texlive 2017

Comment: but the 2016 one with the wider background has a mis-matched brace group in some package, the log ends with `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 1061 ({)`